# Looking for a .net Control like the one used in Task manager

Tags: .net, controls

Anyone know where I can find a Windows.Forms control like this one here? I would like to use one in my application[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Just make your own.  Derive a class from Control and override OnPaint() to draw the bar and the text.